# How to fit my layout to screen using xml, grid layout / linear layout does not work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have to make this kind of layout but I have no idea how to make it fit to the screen using xml code. There is a way using java code and getting screen resolution and then setting width and height of all components but it's not a good idea I think. Using grid layout you cant fit elements, using linear you cant make few in one line like this. I also tried to use few linear layout, but in this case its impossible to locate elements like I want to. Do you have any guess how to solve it?!

how to show this type of **custom grid component**

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFCFX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  multiple nested relative layouts, and use the layout_weight attribute to properly size them, and layout_below, layout_toRightOf, etc. to position them the way you want.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

Comment: @Charliee If my answer helped you, it would be nice to _accept_ it, by clicking the checkmark next to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** As we know the percent support library is deprecated from API level 26. `ConstraintLayout` is the new way to achieve the same flat xml structure.

[**Updated Github Project**](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)

**Updated Samples:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_thirty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff8800"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fifty_fifty_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fifty_fifty_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fifty_thirty"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fifty_thirty"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Deprecated**

Well not to worry your layout can fit any way you want it by android's percent support library.

[Demo HERE !](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)

[GitHub project HERE !](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample)

Consider this simple sample for demo.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ff7acfff"
        android:text="20% - 50%"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:text="80%-50%"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

[image: 50_50_percent_demo]

Really awesome !!!